# How can I handle errors with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I'm working on a Rails application using HTTParty to make HTTP requests. How can I handle HTTP errors with HTTParty? Specifically, I need to catch HTTP 502 & 503 and other errors like connection refused and timeout errors.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

An instance of [HTTParty::Response](http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/master/HTTParty/Response) has a `code` attribute which contains the status code of the HTTP response. It's given as an integer. So, something like this:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json')

case response.code
  when 200
    puts "All good!"
  when 404
    puts "O noes not found!"
  when 500...600
    puts "ZOMG ERROR #{response.code}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was planning on doing. Was wondering if there was any other way to do error handling.

Comment: This answer doesn't address connection failures.

Comment: As to preethinarayan's comment, if you wanted to to catch/rescue the errors instead, you could always do something like:

   raise blablahblah if response.code != 200

I'm actually going to be doing something similar...

Comment: response.code always returns 200 if the error is handled in the application. How to tackle that??

Answer (score 50):

**This answer addresses connection failures.** If a URL isn´t found the status code won´t help you. Rescue it like this:

```
 begin
   HTTParty.get('http://google.com')
 rescue HTTParty::Error
   # don´t do anything / whatever
 rescue StandardError
   # rescue instances of StandardError,
   # i.e. Timeout::Error, SocketError etc
 end
```

For more information see: [this github issue](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/209)

Comment: Never catch everything. You should catch `HTTParty`s error base class.

Comment: Maybe the idea is to catch errors in the HTTParty code. HTTParty could raise errors that are not `HTTParty::Errors`.

Comment: If there is no network at all I get a `SocketError`, just something to be aware of. You can try unplugging your ethernet cable to see this happen.

Comment: I use `HTTP_ERRORS` from suspenders, https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders/blob/master/templates/errors.rb and `HTTParty::Error` https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/Error, e.g. `rescue HTTParty::Error, *HTTP_ERRORS`

Answer (score 28):

You can also use such handy predicate methods as `ok?` or `bad_gateway?` like this:

```
response = HTTParty.post(uri, options)
response.success?
```

The full list of all the possible responses can be found under [`Rack::Utils::HTTP_STATUS_CODES`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/v3.0.4.1/lib/rack/utils.rb#L538) constant.

Comment: I just read this comment and it helped me a lot also! https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/456#issuecomment-498778386