# Rails how to check API request URL before pull

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I am looking for a way to check if the API URL exists before making a request using HTTParty. Currently, if the URL does not exist, the HTTParty request errors.

I tried following this [Check if URL exists in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908017/check-if-url-exists-in-ruby):

```
api_url = "http://api.meetup.com/LA-Computer-Science-Reading-Group/events?photo-host=public&page=20&sig_id=215634693&sig=0be729af948c1a17ce5f35faa9fcedd5ae22de56"
require "net/http"
url_request = URI.parse(api_url)
req = Net::HTTP.new(url_request.host, url_request.port)
res = req.request_head(url_request.path)

@check = res 

response = HTTParty.get(api_url)
```

view:

```
<%= @check.inspect %>
#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

But if I change the URL to something that does not exist, such as:

```
http://api.meeeeeetup.com/LA-Computer-Science-Reading-Group/events?photo-host=public&page=20&sig_id=215634693&sig=0be729af948c1a17ce5f35faa9fcedd5ae22de56`
```

The page still errors with `getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Also, the URL request I want to check is a XML request:

```
http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=#{publisher_key}&q=java&l=austin%2C+tx&sort=&radius=&st=&jt=&start=&limit=&fromage=&filter=&latlong=1&co=us&chnl=&userip=&useragent=&v=2
```

and using the idea above, this API URL does not return a successful call. Instead it returns a `#<Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed 405 Method Not Allowed readbody=true>`.

I'm not sure about emulating a browser to check the results that way or if there is an easier way to check for validity of the API URL request before the HTTParty request.

Comment: Why can't httparty simply make the request and fail if invalid url?

Comment: @Joel_Blum I found if I pass in the invalid URL to HTTParty, it would just error with `getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` and break the app. I'm not sure how to catch that error or if HTTParty has a way to check the URL response before failing.

Comment: You can check a URL for validity; that's different than ensuring the endpoint *exists*. But your "invalid" URL example isn't an invalid URL, it just doesn't exist. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26768085/438992

Comment: Thank you, @DaveNewton. I was able to get the check working based on your comment. I also edited my question so it was more accurate.

Comment: @tshckr Please add the answer as an answer, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Dave Newton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) from the comments I was able to get the check working. I also edited my question to reflect that it was not about the 'validity' of the URL. But it was that the URL does not exist.

Based on: [How can I handle errors with HTTParty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909596/how-can-i-handle-errors-with-httparty/26768085#26768085).

Solution:

```
 begin
   response = HTTParty.get(url) 
 rescue HTTParty::Error
   # don´t do anything / whatever
   puts "=========ERROR=============="
 rescue StandardError
   # rescue instances of StandardError,
   # i.e. Timeout::Error, SocketError etc
   puts "=========STANDARD ERROR=============="
 end
```

Then added a check `if !response.nil?`, so if the HTTParty request returned an error. `response` would be `nil` and the block of code would be ignored.