# How to implement Retry on RSPEC Please?

Tags: ruby, api, rspec

I would like to implement a retry for a number of times if the server is unavailable at that time!. Is possible?.

```
require 'httparty'
require 'pry'
require_relative '../../env.rb'

RSpec.describe 'Validar a api de usuários' do

  it 'Deve retornar 200 para API DRIVE THRU' do
    response = HttParty.get("#{URLS['drive_thru']}/v1/health/live")
    expect(response.code).to eql(200)
    expect(response.parsed_response).to be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: It would be the same way you'd retry in regular code. E.g. a loop with a rescue or conditional. What is the error case you want to retry on?

Comment: Hello my friend, I honestly don't know how to do it. I want that if the api fails to run for 3X and if the server is unavailable it will present the message: "Server unavailable"

Comment: But the specific details matter. What exactly happens right now when the server is unavailable? Do you get a SocketError raised? Or just a different response code?

Comment: Hi Max Morning!!..  fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/grupofleury/drive-thru/automacao-api.git/': The requested URL returned error: 503

Comment: Hi Max Morning!!.. fatal: unable to access 'gitlab.com/grupofleury/drive-thru/automacao-api.git': The requested URL returned error: 503 – Silvio Aulik 2 days ago   Delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general purpose retry system might look like this:

```
tries_left = 3
loop do
  break if tries_left == 0
  begin
    result = do_thing
  rescue SomeError => e
    tries_left -= 1
  end
end
```

You have to replace `do_thing` and `SomeError` with your HTTParty call and whatever error is being raised.

Also see [How can I handle errors with HTTParty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909596/how-can-i-handle-errors-with-httparty/7909823)